# Check checkbox when pressing on table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to allow my users to press on the table row to check a checkbox.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="toggleIt(this)">
            <input type="checkbox"/> Option 1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="toggleIt(this)">
            <input type="checkbox"/> Option 2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
function toggleIt(myTd) {
   $(myTd).find('input').prop('checked', !$(myTd).find('input').prop('checked'));
}
```

This works great until you press the checkbox itself, then it wont work. My guess is that the checkbox checks itself, then the javascript is run and it reverses it again.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/toxu1v2o/1/

EDIT: Sorry for not clarifying, I need to be able to press the whole `td` tag, This wont work with labels: http://jsfiddle.net/toxu1v2o/4/

**SOLUTION:**

Instead of using `this`, use `event`. Then check if its the checkbox being pressed or not. Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/toxu1v2o/17/

Answer (score 3):

You don't need JavaScript for this - just wrap the `checkbox` and the text in a `<label />` element:

```css
td {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
label {
  padding: 40px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Option 1
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Option 2
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think the idea is that the OP wants to be able to click anywhere in the td and for that to select the checkbox. if you add this to your and their fiddles, you will see what I mean. `td {border:1px solid; width:200px}`

Comment: @wf4 in that case `label { display: block; }` There is no point making this behaviour in JS when you get it completely for free, cross browser in standard HTML.

Comment: It's still possible, you just need to amend the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/toxu1v2o/5/

Answer (score 1):

you can try in this way

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <label for="cb1">Op1</label>
            <input id="cb1" type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="cb2">Op2</label> 
          <input id="cb2" type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both your `input` & `key` with `<label>` tag. Hope it'll work!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?
And what version of jquery are you using?

```
$('td').click(function(){
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'true');
});
```